# SQL Delete Query where record without match is deleted?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, sql-delete

I'm trying to get a delete query working but keep getting runtime errors.
What I'm trying to do:
Take one table, compare it against another table and delete records in the latter table where the id field doesn't match/is blank.
Basically, I'm trying to delete records that are in the 2nd table but not in the first.

The SQL for my Query is as follows(it was generated by access and is probably totally wrong):

```
DELETE [Training Summary].*
FROM [Training Summary] LEFT JOIN [Temporary for MRC Update] ON [Training Summary].[DHV ID Number] = [Temporary for MRC Update].[Id]
WHERE ((([Temporary for MRC Update].Id) Is Null));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047566/help-with-delete-where-not-in-query?rq=1

Comment: Don't you think it might be helpful if you told us what those "runtime errors" actually *say*?

Comment: @JohnnyBones They can't upvote until they reach 15 rep, but you're right: In 11 answers over 8 questions you'd hope that at least one of them would be worthy of an [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: That's my bad, I've been crazy busy. i went back and accepted people who helped me (as Johnny did (alot...))

Comment: @sammorris - I have two questions; Which table, exactly, do you want to delete the data from (give us the name please, so it's perfectly clear) and can you tell us the exact wording of the runtime error you're getting when you run your original code?  Unless one of the below answers has already helped, in which case answers to these questions aren't necessary.  My wild guess is it might be a Type Conversion error.  If that's the case, make sure your data types are identical in both tables (for example, the ID field is an INTEGER in both tables).

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE Table2.*
FROM Table2
WHERE ID NOT IN (
     SELECT ID
     FROM Table1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE * FROM [Training Summary]
WHERE [DHV ID Number] NOT IN (
     SELECT [Id]
     FROM [Temporary for MRC Update]
)
```

Comment: This throws a error asking for the table to be selected. What am i missing here?

Comment: *@sam morris*, Corrected my answer.  I missed the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

This is doing the opposite of what you want. It will delete records that are in the 1st table but not the 2nd. Just switch the names around.